# Can Exchange email password be set different from AD password?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, exchange, active-directory

I have to access my Exchange email via POP and Outlook. From what I know it is really easy to recover passwords used by Outlook accounts - there are dozens of utilities for that. If my email password becomes compromised I'd like my AD password be safe.

Can Exchange email password be set different from AD password?

Comment: "AD" is Active Domain - in case it was confused with "Administrator"

Answer (score 0):

You may create similar account like admin  and have all email forward to this box. This way, your AD will be safe.